# how to calculate text width in vb6

Tags: vb6

I know there is a method textwidth to calculate the text width of a string.

But we are having 2 forms which has its own separate list box. But we are going a maintain a common .bas file which holds the code for it.

For example let the form name be form1 and form2. Width can be calculated by form1.TextWidth(ListBox.list(i)) and form2.TextWidth(ListBox.list(i))

Now the problem is, since we are maintaining a common bas file for both these projects, form2 project doesn't know what is form1.

Suggest me some ideas to get the width of the string.

Overall I need to add horizontal scroll bar to the list box, if it exceeds the maximum width of a string. So if maxwidth>listboxWidth then, I will call the horizontalscroll bar method to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

This works :)
ListBox.Parent.TextWidth(ListBox.List(i))

Comment: Of course that fails to give a correct result unless the ListBox and its Parent have exactly the same font settings.  Otherwise it is the obvious way to go as illustrated in sample code in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

you will be using WINAPI function to enable Horizontal Scrollbar, so you will not need to do conversions from Pixels To Twips, right?.

all you need is a function like this one:

```
function StringWidth(pStr as string) as long
  dim sz as SIZE
  hdc=CreateCompatibleDC(0)
  oldFont=SelectObject(hdc,ifont.handle)
  call GetTextExtentPoint32 (hdc,pStr,len(pstr), sz)
  oldFont=SelectObject(hdc,oldFont)
  call DeleteDC(hdc)

  StringWidth=sz.cx
end function
```